# getting error create test when implement Activity

Tags: android

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements AppCompatActivity

i am getting error on AppCompatActivity it shows error create test

Comment: AppCompatActivity is not defined as an interface. You cannot implement it

Answer (score 0):

Could you please post more of your code?
Why would you need to implement AppCompatActivity anyways? You don't need it for creating a Custom Adapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private LayoutInflater _layoutInflater;
Context context;

public CustomAdapter(){
    super();
   }

public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this._layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   }
}
```

Works like a charm for me (I removed most of the unneccesary code so obviously you have to change it)

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your Adapter in android

```
public CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] prgmNameList, int[] prgmImages) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    result=prgmNameList;
    context=mainActivity; // this context for activity
    imageId=prgmImages;
 LayoutInflater inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
             getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```

may be this help you

Comment: thng getting solution